# Heroku Postgres Django: Best database configuration for efficency?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, heroku, relational-database

I am building an eCommerce application that will be hosted on Heroku, use their Postgres database, and the app will be built with Django.  There will be a massive amount of products & product categories with detailed information for each product category.  Each product category will have very different fields. For example computers vs clothing.  What is the best way to set up the data structure? (Opt a) Lump all detail fields into one table.  (Opt B) create a separate table for each type of product detail. (Opt C) One table for all products and details. Or some other option i have not thought of?  Below is an extremely abbreviated example of the data structures and associated fields.

OPT A

```
Table 1 = All products
- Id
- Name
- Model#
- Manufacturer
- Image
- Foreign Key to appropriate product details

Table 2 = Computers (product detail)
- Ram
- Cpu

Table 3 = Clothing (product detail)
- Size
- Color
```

OPT B

```
Table 1 = Products
- Id
- Name
- Model
- Make
- Image
- Foreign Key to product detail

Table 2 = Product Detail
- Size
- Color
- Ram
- Cpu
```

OPT C

```
Table 1 = Products
- Id
- Name
- Model#
- Manufacturer
- Image
- Size
- Color
- Ram
- Cpu
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is easier to begin with a well-normalized design and denormalize as necessary than go the other way.  So I would start out with option A.  Keep in mind that this means that your average reads are narrower, which means fewer pages are retrieved from disk overall.  Assuming sane indexing, definitely you should start with the most normalized design and then if you run into troubles that are not able to handle with better indexing, then denormalize as absolutely required.

However, such denormalization is not the norm for OLTP applications as it rarely helps overall throughput and poses significant complexity costs.